# Why is my diffuse illumination calculated wrongly in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, vector-graphics

The equations I use for L, V and R are these:

```
Vector3 L = (P.subtract(light.getPosition())).normalised();
Vector3 V = P.subtract(O).normalised();
Vector3 R = L.normalised().reflectIn(N.normalised()).normalised();

ColorRGB diffuse = C_diff.scale(k_d).scale(I);
double N_dot_L = N.normalised().dot(L.normalised());
N_dot_L = Math.max(0.0, N_dot_L);
diffuse = diffuse.scale(N_dot_L);

ColorRGB specular = C_spec.scale(k_s).scale(I);
double R_dot_V = R.normalised().dot(V.normalised());
R_dot_V = Math.pow(Math.max(0.0, R_dot_V), alpha);
specular = specular.scale(R_dot_V);
```

Where

- L is the light direction vector from the light source to object
- V is the direction vector from object to camera
- R is the reflected ray direction vector, which is opposite of L about the normal to a surface
- C_diff and C_spec and alpha are constants in the equation

Unfortunately, SO does not let me post my picture so I can only include it in a link (see below).
[Image of Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4oWc.jpg)

As this is a major project I'm unable to see why my implementations are wrong when I follow so closely to the equation. I've narrowed down the source of error to this code snippet and hope someone can tell me where my code went wrong.

I can't seem to find the error as it follows the equation exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a misunderstanding of the required sign of `N_dot_L`.

The way you calculate `L` gives a vector going from the light to the point on the surface; if the ray reaches the surface then the dot product `N_dot_L` would be *negative* instead of positive - so by taking `Math.max` of it and 0, you are *always* clamping it to zero for surfaces exposed to the light.

To remedy this, take the light ray vector in the *opposite direction*, i.e. `L = ((light.getPosition()).subtract(P)).normalized()`.

Comment: Thanks! But why wouldn't the light need to go to the surface for illumination? This seems to have L going back to the light source instead?

Comment: @user102938475 It does need to go to the surface in a physical sense, but that's not necessarily how the math works. In rendering, imaginary rays are cast from each pixel to the surface, then from that point to the light, whereas in the real world the reverse happens